# A way to change the path to GTK+ themes?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

After a few tries I realized where GTK+ finds it's icons and themes under windows.

And this forces me to use a specific file structure like shown below.

```
project/                // Imaginge this is my root directory
  bin/                  // Where binaries are stored
    *.dll
    program.exe
  share/                // Has to be located exactly here. Otherwise GTK+ will not find themes
    icons/              // Here the themes are stored
      ...
```

My Question: Is there a way to tell GTK+ another location for themes? Maybe I am willing to translate these themes somewhere in an assets/ folder. How do I let GTK+ finding them?

And please notice that I really searched the internet for a solution and I did not find it since now.

Darth Moon

Comment: I assume that you're using `gtk` and not `gtkmm`, hence removed the `C++` tag.

Comment: Unfortunately, there documentation is very sparse on where to put 'stuff' when it comes to gtk cross platform development. To  build gtk from source itself sometimes sounds a tedious task. That said [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36820775/1620779) answer which deals with gtk python port also give a folder layout similar to your project structure. I guess that the same folder structure need to be followed on deployment too..